# TOC with Label layer in ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, dijit.form

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript 3.7 API's and i am using agsjs.dijit.TOC control and it is working fine but when i added Label Layer in my map that time Label layer is coming fine but  TOC is not working Properly.

While Pressing the checkbox to On-Off the Layer it is working fine but regarding the feature layer i added one Label layer that is not getting On-Off

Can anyone tell me how to Switch-Off or On the Label Layer.

Thanks in Advance.

I am Pasting some code..

```
        Var load = function () {
    require(["dojo/_base/Color", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/renderers/ScaleDependentRenderer"],
    function (Color, TextSymbol, SimpleRenderer, ScaleDependentRenderer) {
    var statesColor = new Color("#666");
    var fieldLabel = new TextSymbol().setColor(statesColor);
    fieldLabel.font.setSize("4pt");
    fieldLabel.font.setFamily("arial");

    statesLabelRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(fieldLabel);
    return statesLabelRenderer;
});
    }
    var layers = [];  
    var layer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(url, {
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields: ["*"]                                    
    });
    layers.push(layer);

    layerInfo.push({ layer: layer, title: item["LookupDisplayDesc"], boxLabel: item["LookupDisplayDesc"], id: layer.id, checked: layer.visibleAtMapScale, slider: true });

if (item["LookupLongDesc"] != null && item["LookupLongDesc"] != "") {
    var fieldNames = item["LookupLongDesc"].split(",");
    var labelFields = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i < fieldNames.length ; i++) {
    labelFields = labelFields + "${" + fieldNames[i].trim() + "},";
}
    labelFields = labelFields.slice(0, -1).trim();
    load();
    var labelLayer = new esri.layers.LabelLayer();
    labelLayer.addFeatureLayer(layer, statesLabelRenderer, labelFields);
    layers.push(labelLayer);
    }
}
map.addLayers(layers);


 dojo.connect(map, 'onLayersAddResult', function (results) {
                if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
                    var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
                        map: map,
                        layerInfos: layerInfo
                    }, "legendDiv");
                    legendDijit.startup();
                }
                toc = new agsjs.dijit.TOC({
                    map: map,
                    layerInfos: layerInfo
                }, 'LayerDiv');
                toc.startup();                
            });
```

Comment: Guys i am waiting for the reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with how TOC works, I build my layer logic manually.  If you go the manual route you can just use show and hide like below or use setVisibleLayers like [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html).

A simple show and hide in your layer logic would be:

```
labelLayer.hide();
labelLayer.show();
```